# return the last record of an "order" in a logging table

Tags: sql

One of my business clients has asked me to provide specific data that doesn't seem to be friendly to reporting on (we want to return only exit data).
I've created a much simplified version of our table to help simplify my request.

[image: table example 1]

What I'm trying to do is return only the last record from each order. so based on the example table I provided, the result would need to look something like:

[image: expected results]

I'm sure this will require some sort of subquerying using a max  lineitem but I'm not even sure how to get started. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery is often a simple and performant solution:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.lineitem = (select max(t2.lineitem)
                    from t t2
                    where t2.orderid = t.orderid
                   );
```

Answer (score 1):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where orderid = t.orderid and lineitem > t.lineitem
)
```

or if your database supports window function `row_number()`:

```
select t.orderid, t.lineitem, t.itemdescription, t.price 
from (
  select t.* ,
    row_number() over (partition by orderid order by lineitem desc) rn
  from tablename t
) t 
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3ff19df703ea7b3650fc20c4f887346).
Results:

```
> orderid | lineitem | itemdescription | price
> ------: | -------: | :-------------- | ----:
>     105 |        3 | Oranges         |   2.50
>     106 |        4 | Cake            |   6.00
>     107 |        2 | Apples          |   2.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I called your table `orders` :

```
select o1.* from orders o1
where o1.lineitem = (select max(lineitem) from orders o2 where o2.orderid = o1.orderid);
```

edit: an earlier and similar answer was provided by Gordon Linoff.